# Is a model-based recursive partitioning model from the family of the mixed effect models?

Tags: r, tree, lme4, mixed-models, party

I was wondering if it is correct to say that a model-based recursive partitioning model (**mob**, package partykit) is of
the family of the mixed-effect models.

My point is that a mixed effect model provides different parameters for each random effect and this is also what does a mob model. The main difference I see is that a mob partitions itself the random effects.

Here is an example:

```
library(partykit); library(lme4)
set.seed(321)

##### Random data
V1 <- runif(100); V2 <- sample(1:3, 100, replace=T)
V3 <- jitter(ifelse(V2 == 1, 2*V1+3, ifelse(V2==2, -1*V1+2, V1)), amount=.2) 

##### Mixed-effect model
me <- lmer(V3 ~ V1 + (1 + V1|V2))
coef(me) #linear model coefficients from the mixel effect model

#$V2
#  (Intercept)         V1
#1  2.99960082  1.9794378
#2  1.96874586 -0.8992926
#3  0.01520725  1.0255424

##### MOB
fit <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL)  lm(y ~ x)
mo <- mob(V3 ~ V1|V2, fit=fit) #equivalent to lmtree
coef(mo) #linear model (same) coefficients from the mob

#      (Intercept) x(Intercept)        xV1
#2  2.99928854           NA  1.9804084
#4  1.97185661           NA -0.9047805
#5  0.01333292           NA  1.0288309
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the kind of linear regression-based MOB (`lmtree`) is not a mixed-effects type of model. However, you used the MOB tree to estimate an interaction model (or nested effect) and indeed mixed-effects models can also be used to do so.

Your data-generating process implements a different intercept and `V1` slope for every level of `V2`. If this interaction is known it can be easily recovered by a suitable linear regression with interaction effect (but `V2` should be a categorical factor variable for this).

```
V2 <- factor(V2)
mi <- lm(V3 ~ 0 + V2 / V1)
matrix(coef(mi), ncol = 2)
##            [,1]       [,2]
## [1,] 2.99928854  1.9804084
## [2,] 1.97185661 -0.9047805
## [3,] 0.01333292  1.0288309
```

Note that the model fit is equivalent to `lm(V3 ~ V1 * V2)` but uses a different contrast coding for the coefficients.

The estimates obtained above are exactly identical to th `lmtree()` output (or manually using `mob()` + `lm()` as you did in your post):

```
coef(lmtree(V3 ~ V1 | V2))
##   (Intercept)         V1
## 2  2.99928854  1.9804084
## 4  1.97185661 -0.9047805
## 5  0.01333292  1.0288309
```

The main difference is that you had to tell `lm()` exactly which interaction to consider. `lmtree()`, on the other hand, "learned" the interaction in a data-driven way. Admittedly, in this case there is not so much to learn...but `lmtree()` could have decided without any split or with two splits instead of performing all possible splits.

Finally, your `lmer(V3 ~ V1 + (1 + V1 | V2))` specification also estimates a nested (or interaction) effect. However, it uses a different estimation technology with random effects instead of full fixed effects. Also, here you have to prespecify the interaction.

In short: `lmtree()` can be considered as a way to find interaction effects in a data-driven way. But these interactions are not estimated with random effects, hence not a mixed-effects model.

P.S.: It is possible to combine `lmtree()` and `lmer()` but that's a different story. If you are interested see package https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=glmertree and the accomanying paper.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is perfectly clear. Is there any reason to trust more the lmer estimations of coefficient over the lmtree estimations? Rather than combining lmtree with a nested lmer as does the glmetree package, is it possible to combine a lmtree with another a nested lmtree (eg something like 2lmtree(V3~V1|V2|V4))?

Comment: The random-effects estimation of the interactions with `lmer()` is preferable if you know the grouping factor but it has many levels. Fixed-effects estimation with `lm()` is preferable if the grouping is known but has relatively few levels (compared to the sample size). `lmtree()` has the advantage that it can discover groups in a data-driven way. As for the nested tree, I'm not sure what you mean. Using `lmtree(V3 ~ V1 | V2 + V4)` will determine recursively whether to use `V2` or `V4` or both for grouping.

Comment: Thanks a million for sharing your knowledge ! It is very helpful. Regarding my 2nd question, I will open a new post to illustrate it